# How do I make a javascript function available after the document is loaded in Blazor?

Tags: blazor

Without using Blazor,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('hello')
        // what you want to initialize
    });
</script>
```

With Blazor, do I just put the above script in `wwwroot/index.html` and call it from Blazor razor page in `OnInitializedAsync` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blazor Server App you can add a script tag (in _Host.cshtml file) to your JavaScript file like this:

```
 <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
 <script src="exampleJsInterop.js"></script>
```

Your JS file should be placed in the wwwroot folder

And you can call your JavaScript functions from the pair OnAfterRender(Async) as the following code snippet demonstrates:

```
 @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<div @ref="divElement">Text during render</div>

@code {
    private ElementReference divElement;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(
                "exampleJsInterop.setElementText", divElement, "Text after render");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Since a Blazor Server app is usually prerendering, JavaScript is not yet available, so you have to wait until your app is rendered, and only then call JavaScript functions. Note also that the code above check if this is the first time the app is rendered...this is the place where you should initialize your JavaScript object.

Note: The above is not applicable to WebAssembly Apps, as JavaScript is available from the very beginning.

In WebAssembly Apps you should place the  tag that references your JavaScript file in the wwwroot/index.html, like the following:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script src="exampleJsInterop.js"></script>
```

Note that you still need to call your JavaScript functions from the OnAfterRender(Async) pair.

I hope that helps! If you get stuck, let me know

Comment: The location of the js file shouldn't matter, according to the documentation.

[(The first parameter of InvokeVoidAsync is) an identifier for the function to invoke. For example, the value "someScope.someFunction" will invoke the function window.someScope.someFunction.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.jsinterop.jsruntimeextensions.invokevoidasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

The `OnAfterRenderAsync` not worked for me and some js objects in libraries was not defined even in `OnAfterRenderAsync` or `OnInitializedAsync`.

I solved the problem with the `setTimeout` global method:

```
window.startKustomerChat = (kustomerBrandId) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        Kustomer.start({ brandId: kustomerBrandId }, function () {
            console.log('Kustomer Chat Widget started!');
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me,because I was using api call, I had to remove firstRender in if.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await FetchData();
}
public async Task FetchData()
{
    data = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<ResultDto>("/api/v1/GetData");
}
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (data != null)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("RenderTopCoin");
    }

    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```