# Bootstrap scrollspy not working in Blazor

Tags: bootstrap-4, blazor, blazor-server-side, scrollspy

I am working in a Blazor project and I wanted to add Bootstrap's scrollspy.

I have this in my _Host.cshtml file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have this page:

```
<div class="mt-5 ml-3 mr-1">
  <div>
    <h3 class="d-inline">name</h3><h3 class="d-inline">></h3> <h3 class="d-inline">Change profile</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div id="list-example" class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-1">Credentials</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-2">Office</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-3">Home</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-4">Item 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#list-example" data-offset="0" class="scrollspy-example" style="position:relative;height: 200px;overflow-y: scroll;">
        <h4 id="list-item-1">Credentials</h4>
        <p>...</p>
        <h4 id="list-item-2">Office</h4>
        <p>...</p>
        <h4 id="list-item-3">Home</h4>
        <p>...</p>
        <h4 id="list-item-4">Item 4</h4>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I paste this in JSFiddle, it is working: https://jsfiddle.net/6p4r8obj/

When I paste this in BlazorFiddle, it is not working: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/li502n7x

When I try it in my project on localhost, it is sometimes working when I click on 'clear cache and force reload', the second time I click on 'clear cache and force reload' it no longer works.

Are there some extra steps I can/need to do to get it to work in Blazor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the script try execute before the page is created, see: [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62859002/how-do-i-make-a-javascript-function-available-after-the-document-is-loaded-in-bl/62859180#62859180).

As the javascript executed is

```
$(window).on(EVENT_LOAD_DATA_API$2, function () {
    var scrollSpys = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR_DATA_SPY));
    var scrollSpysLength = scrollSpys.length;

    for (var i = scrollSpysLength; i--;) {
      var $spy = $(scrollSpys[i]);

      ScrollSpy._jQueryInterface.call($spy, $spy.data());
    }
  });
```

You can try (I don't know if work) write your .js

**Updated** thanks to Kim Went, replace `ScrollSpy._jQueryInterface.call($spy, $spy.data());` to `$.fn['scrollspy'].call($spy, $spy.data());`

```
checkScrollSpy=function(){
    var scrollSpys = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR_DATA_SPY));
    var scrollSpysLength = scrollSpys.length;

    for (var i = scrollSpysLength; i--;) {
      var $spy = $(scrollSpys[i]);

      $.fn['scrollspy'].call($spy, $spy.data());
    }
}
```

And call this function in `OnAfterRenderAsync`

Comment: Thank you! I just added your code and changed `ScrollSpy._jQueryInterface.call($spy, $spy.data());` to `$.fn['scrollspy'].call($spy, $spy.data());` and it is working!

Comment: The scrollspy is now working, but for me there's still an issue related to anchors in Blazor. Indeed, when you have a local anchor in blazor (`href`starting with `#`), Blazor will redirect you to the path using the `base href`' you've defined and add the anchor. To make it work, you'll have to use the absolute path from `NavigationManager`, which will cause issues with client features such as Bootstrap scrollspy.